# Hyperlinks: Text vs. Direct - why do the results differ?

Tags: html, email, url, browser, hyperlink

Potentially a very basic question - forgive my ignorance as I'm still learning, but this is a question that arose while working with a colleague that it would be useful to know while I build my understanding.

We had a URL that we needed to link through on an email, however depending on how the link is displayed, it produces different results.

When the URL is attached to text in an email, the user is able to access the intended page. However, when the exact same link is pasted directly into the address bar, the user is directed to a firewall/login page.

Similarly, if the link attached to the text has been shortened (i.e. through Bitly) then the user is again directed to the firewall. I can only assume that this is because the link translates within the address bar after the text link is clicked, leading to the same result.

Any knowledge on this would be greatly appreciated in case we need to circumvent this problem in future. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the `Referer` header is checked...

Comment: I've just had a look at that - makes sense! Thanks. :)

Comment: Do you use cookies with the `SameSite=strict` flag?